# ¿No puedo mostrar una imagen desde una carpeta?

Tags: php

Quiero crear una página web que mediante el uso de PHP  que  se declare una variable con la ruta de una imagen y la muestre por pantalla, pero no para de salirme fallos como si el codigo lo tuviera mal, este es el codigo que llevo.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Imágenes dinámicas de una carpeta en php</title>
</head>
<?php
$directory = "4";
$dirint = dir($directory);

while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
{
    echo $archivo;
}
$dirint->close();
?>
<body>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estaría bien saber qué fallos te salen, por eso de poder ayudarte a solucionarlos, no crees? Además, imprime la ruta antes de intentar leerla a ver si está correcta, lo mismo te llevas una sorpresa

Comment: Esto:                                                                 Warning: dir(4,4): El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado. (code: 2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Ejercicios de clase\4\4.php on line 7

Warning: dir(4): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Ejercicios de clase\4\4.php on line 7



Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function read() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Ejercicios de clase\4\4.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Ejercicios de clase\4\4.php on line 9

Comment: No lo pongas aquí, añádelo a la pregunta. De todas maneras ahí tienes tu error `No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Ejercicios de clase\4\4.php on line 7`. Vamos, que el directorio que intentas leer en la línea 7 no existe. Siempre hay que debuguear antes de preguntar